# Radio Buttons ng-value, ng-model and ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple form that renders items and provide radio buttons. Radio buttons are rendered as expected. My goal is to get 'item.chosen' value in the selectRadioButton function. I am getting the item but item.chosen is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?
HTML:

```
<div class="item" ng-if="ctrl.items" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="item.chosen"
        ng-value=true ng-click="ctrl.selectRadioButton(item)">
</div>
```

JS:

```
this.selectRadioButton = function(item){
    if(item.chosen) {
        console.log('Got the chosen value');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the piece of template where you define `ctrl`? Maybe `$ctrl` should be used instead?

Comment: Radio buttons are rendered as expected, which means ctrl is defined correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code of how you should work with radio buttons on AnuglarJS.

Controller:

```
  angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.color = {
        name: 'blue'
      };
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "id": "12345",
        "value": "green"
      };
    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  <tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

Check [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) for more info